# awk to cut portion of a field and still print entire line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, cut

I have this line:

```
08:30:02.480507 IP 192.168.100.150.65119 > 192.168.100.151:53 59865 [1au] A? click.em.redbox.com. (48)
```

I need to cut out the ".480507" in the timestamp so the line looks like this:

```
08:30:02 IP 192.168.100.150.65119 > 192.168.100.151.53: 59865 [1au] A? click.em.redbox.com. (48)
```

I've fumbled around with several awk and cut statements but to no avail. I'd like to find an awk one liner but sed may be a better solution for this. I just don't know quite enough about either one when it comes to cutting in this fashion.

NOTE: This is an example, and the portion of the timestamp I need to cut out will not be the same, as I need to perform this action on a number of lines all with different timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` probably the simplest way is to do a regular expression substitution on the first whitespace-separated field, replacing everything from the period to the end of the field:

```
awk '{sub(/\..*/,"",$1)}1' somefile
```

Comment: Yes! exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would use awk

`awk --posix '{ gsub(/\.[[:digit:]]{6}/, "", $1); print }' filename`

Will target the first field (space delimited) and search for a . followed by 6 numbers and empty it out.

Answer (score 0):

with GNU `sed`

```
sed -r 's/^([^.]+)\.[0-9]+ /\1 /' filename
```

- `^([^.]+)` capture starting string upto first dot character
- `\.[0-9]+` match dot character followed by more than 1 digit characters

and if number of characters is consistent as given in the example,

```
sed -r 's/^(.{8}).{7} /\1 /' filename
```